# Javascript + Date conversion in IE8 and Safari

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am trying to convert a datetime (raw format in UTC: 2012-12-05T21:55:00) to readable local time format but the output varies across browsers:

```
DateTime = new Date(DateTime);
alert(DateTime);
```

**In Chrome it appears as:**

```
Wed Feb 20 2013
05:31:00 GMT +0800
(Malay Peninsula
Standard Time)
```

**and in IE:**

```
Wed Feb 20 05:31:00
UTC+0800 2013
```

Hence, I applied a **.format** to it:

```
DateTime = new Date(DateTime);
DateTime.format('dd MMM, yyyy hh:mm tt')
alert(DateTime);
```

This format appears good and consistent across Chrome and IE9:

```
20 Feb, 2013 05:31 AM
```

but there's an issue in displaying it in IE8 and Safari, it shows the date as:

```
NaN, 000NaN
NaN:NaN AM
```

I tried other JS plugins like date ninja but no help either. Can anyone advise how to go about the NaN issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced 'exactly' the same issue you are facing a few months back. Use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). It gives consistent date formats in Chrome, FF and IE(Including IE 8)